# Where a name related to a noun should be placed?

Tags: grammar, nouns

Say I have three kinds of items that I call A, B, and C. Now, I want to ask someone to create one. Which form is the correct one?

> Create an item A.

or

> Create an A item.

?

Comment: Can you explain why "item" is needed at all? Generally one simply says "create a (widget)" "create a (thing)". Perhaps show us an actual example?

Comment: @Catija A,B,C are the categories of items, I want to make it clear which one I ask a user to create. and "item" is necessary

Comment: Create item A,  Create item B,  Create item C - should not raise any eyebrows.

Comment: @MystiSinha and I don't need an article at all?

Comment: @MystiSinha can you please answer why no article is needed?

Comment: _A, B, C_ are very unhelpful as categories here. They tell us absolutely nothing about what **type** of “category of items” you are talking about, which is crucial to knowing which construction to use. Will the item created be _of type_ A/B/C? Or will the item be _named_ A/B/C once it’s created? What are A/B/C? Please edit the question to include this very vital information. There is no possible way to answer the question otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ask someone to create one.

Create **Item A**

Create **Item B**

Create **Item C**

> Because 'item A' is the name of the item.
>   Item A is used like a
>   proper noun, e.g. John Smith. So create ***Item A*** is the correct
>   construction.

It's like "Draw Tom, then Harry ", not "Draw a Tom, then a Harry." 
Create **Item A**, then  **Item B**.

Comment: `A` is a name, `Item` is not a name, does it make any difference?

Comment: @MarcAndreson, as I said - should not raise any eyebrows.

Comment: so can I use "Create **an** item A" ? and then I refer to it "use A", or "use item A", or with an article: "use an item A" ?

Comment: Again, my ears find "create Item A" and "use Item A" idiomatic. Choice is yours.

Comment: and what if I want to add an adjective: "Create a colorful item A" or "Create colorful item A" ?

Answer (score -2):

Do we want to create an 'A' of item (there could be an 'A' of variable or 'A' of parameter) or an item of 'A' (there could be other items)?

Because adjectives are rarely postpositive in English--they usually come before the noun--

> Create an 'A' item.

implies we want to create an item of 'A', and

> Create an item 'A'.

implies we want to create an 'A' of item.

The choice is yours.